# SQL Server return only 1 resultset

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

From my WinForms C# app in NET 3.5 I call a stored procedure in SQL Server.

This stored procedure must return always a result set and a return variable set to 0 or 1.

Here is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[HasRights]  
    @Id char(10),
    @dept char(4) 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @nRows int
    DECLARE @HasRights BIT

    SET @HasRights = 0

    SELECT e.Id, d.DeptId, p.Name
    FROM Employees e  
    INNER JOIN depts d on e.Id = d.Id
    INNER JOIN EmpData p on e.Id = p.Id
    LEFT JOIN OldEmployees o ON e.Id = o.Id
    WHERE e.Id = @Id
      AND o.Id IS NULL
      AND d.DeptId = @dept
      AND e.Type in (100, 200, 300)

    SET @nRows = @@ROWCOUNT      --SCOPE_IDENTITY() would also work

    IF @nRows > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @HasRights = 1
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT e.Id, d.DeptId, p.Name
        FROM Employees e     
        INNER JOIN depts d on e.Id = d.Id
        INNER JOIN EmpData p on e.Id = p.Id
        WHERE e.Id = @Id   
          AND d.DeptId = @dept 
    END

    RETURN @HasRights
END
```

Independently whether employee satisfies some conditions (first result set) or not, the same data is returned. First result set return when conditions are satisfied, and second result set when conditions on first result set are not satisfied, but with the difference that, first result set return variable `@HasRights` is set to 1 and for second result set is set to 0. This allow me from c# code to distinguish them an show an icon or another in a picturebox.

My problem here, is that I need the store procedure to return first result set or second one, but not both at the same time. For example, when conditions on first select are not satisfied, it returns an empty dataset followed by the result set of the second select (not empty). In this case I want only second result set for second select to be returned (not first empty). So how to do it?

I know I firstly can use an EXISTS for the first select as below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[HasRights]  
    @Id char(10),
    @dept char(4) 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @nRows int
    DECLARE @HasRights BIT

    SET @HasRights = 0

    IF EXISTS(SELECT e.Id, d.DeptId, p.Name
              FROM Employees e  
              INNER JOIN depts d on e.Id = d.Id  
              INNER JOIN EmpData p on e.Id = p.Id
              LEFT JOIN OldEmployees o ON e.Id = o.Id
              WHERE e.Id = @Id
                AND o.Id IS NULL
                AND d.DeptId = @dept
                AND e.Type in (100, 200, 300))
    BEGIN
       SELECT e.Id, d.DeptId, p.Name
       FROM Employees e  
       INNER JOIN depts d on e.Id = d.Id
       INNER JOIN EmpData p on e.Id = p.Id
       LEFT JOIN OldEmployees o ON e.Id = o.Id
       WHERE e.Id = @Id
         AND o.Id IS NULL
         AND d.DeptId = @dept
         AND e.Type in (100, 200, 300)               

      SET @HasRights = 1
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT e.Id, d.DeptId, p.Name
        FROM Employees e     
        INNER JOIN depts d on e.Id = d.Id
        INNER JOIN EmpData p on e.Id = p.Id
        WHERE e.Id = @Id   
          AND d.DeptId = @dept 
    END

    RETURN @HasRights
END
```

The problem with this approach is that first select is repeated twice: first when checking if that exists and second if that exists in order to return the result set and I want to avoid this.

Any ideas?

Comment: You could select it into a table variable first and return it from the table variable. Thing is it's probably already cached so it doesn't really matter if you run it twice.

Comment: There's probably a way to fiddle your `WHERE` clause to make it work but i don't understand your logic

Comment: I think I might use one query and determine in c# if employee HasRights by looking at the result set. BTW, you do not return `@HasRights` so what good is that doing anyway?

Comment: @Crowcoder sorry I forgot the return clause at the end of the stored procedure. I have updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have rewritten the stored procedure into the following one:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[HasRights]  
    @Id char(10),
    @dept char(4) 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @HasRights BIT

    SET @HasRights = 0

    IF EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 
              FROM   Employees e  
                     INNER JOIN depts d on e.Id = d.Id
                     INNER JOIN EmpData p on e.Id = p.Id
                     LEFT JOIN OldEmployees o ON e.Id = o.Id
              WHERE  e.Id = @Id
                       AND
                     o.Id IS NULL
                       AND
                     d.DeptId = @dept
                       AND
                     e.Type in (100, 200, 300))
             )
    BEGIN
       SET @HasRights = 1
    END

    SELECT e.Id, d.DeptId, p.Name
    FROM   Employees e  
           INNER JOIN depts d on e.Id = d.Id
           INNER JOIN EmpData p on e.Id = p.Id               
    WHERE  e.Id = @Id
             AND
           d.DeptId = @dept    

    RETURN @HasRights       
END
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to have the same functionality as your originally posted query. If it does, then it is because of some piece of information known only to you.